# Police have to fight with words instead of fists. How does this affect society?

Tags: society, law

In Noviolenstan, police are required to enforce the law with their words, not their fists or any other violent means. If you don't pay your speeding tickets, a police officer will come and explain why speeding is wrong, and why you need to pay the speeding ticket as punishment for what you've done. If you rob a bank, police will convince you to give the money back and to come to jail. When in jail, there are no locks, but the wardens convince you to stay for the term of your sentence.

If you resist arrest of persuasion, the police will ramp up their tactics, such as bringing in sad documentaries about what your specific crime does to society, and bringing in advanced moral philosophy. In the most extreme cases, they may bring your priest, or even worse, your mother, to the crime scene to convince you that what you are doing is wrong.

What affect does this have on society:

- Let's not consider military yet
- The police will never use physical violence or restraint
- Police receive training in ethics, moral philosophy, persuasion, psychology, and related fields
- Distribution of philosophies and ethical systems that encourage illegal behavior is strictly prohibited, considered to be a criminal weapon. Anyone caught with such a system will be told to go to jail for 20 years minimum.

  - There are many edge cases involving the advocacy of the repeal of laws, since thought systems that encourage the repeal of laws often can also be construed to also encourage breaking them. To help mitigate the change of your movement to get a law repealed of being illegal, you often must emphasize that you only want to change the law, not break them if they are not repealed.

Comment: Well, that's one way to end the civilized world.

Comment: "And here we see Chief Officer Pennings of the New York City Roast Department about to apprehend a criminal!"  "Boy you should put that TV back where you done found it and rob a map instead cause you obviously need to find yourself!"                                                                    I'm bad at jokes. But in all seriousness, I don't think this is enough for a real answer, maybe thug culture will change a bit? Like there would be boastful gangsta raps about how the top thug beat a cop... In a debate over Kantian ethics.

Comment: This is kind of broad. Also, how is this different from what Lawyers do?

Comment: It took me about ten seconds when formulating an answer to get from "nonviolent police" to "raised taxes." How in-depth of an answer are you looking for?

Comment: Think of the character of Sgt Hartman in the movie Full Metal Jacket: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlcuPNv8Od8. Now amplify that to 11....

Comment: Maybe all police officers are replaced by unpleasant grandmothers?

Comment: @Aify Lawyers are backed by police who will use violence if need be.

Comment: [Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106697/) with similar concept.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you unintentionally assume that all citizens try to be morally upright, but just didn't know their crime was hurtful. Imagine a robber (let's call him Rob) running out of a bank he just held up. The Noviolenstan policeman saying, "Hey, you really shouldn't have done that. Think about all the people who have been saving money in that bank. You're disrupting their lives." isn't going to do anything. Rob doesn't care. He knew what he was doing, and whether out of desperation or just plain not giving a ****, he robbed the bank anyway. And there is nothing the Noviolenstan police can do about it. Rob can walk straight through their lines, and if they lay a finger on him, he falls down and sues them for police brutality. So essentially, morally corrupt people can get away with anything they want, all they need is a good pair of earplugs.

Though only loosely tied to law enforcement, this scenario reminds me of the sacrosanctity of the [Plebian Tribunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribune_of_the_Plebs) of the Roman Republic. The tribunes could more or less do anything they pleased, from vetoing any legislative action to arresting someone "threatening plebian rights". Any action against the tribunes was punishable by death. Though arguably successful in securing better rights for the plebians, the tribunes stalled many government actions for hundreds of years. They were such a frustration that Julius Caesar was given tribunal power as part of his rise to dictator. The two actual tribunes who attempted to veto this action were impeached and removed from office. I think a similar event would happen in Noviolenstan, where policemen would eventually be so obstructed in their duty that they would resort to similar extreme measures. After all, all they're going to be punished with is a stern ethics lecture.